# How to use UIAlertController in For loop

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've got a scenario where something may need to be renamed and I'd like to use `UIAlertController` to collect the new name. I'd like this to be robust for several changes at once (although it's unlikely, I'd like to support it).

The issue is that I need the loop to continue only when the results of the current `UIAlertController` are in, as it is, the loop continues immediately and of course can't present more than one at once. I've been stuck on this all day and need help.

I need some kind of method that uses the completion hander to give the green light to the next loop iteration.

This is a simplified version of the problem, the changeNames func is in a `UIViewController`.

```
var names = ["Bob","Kate"]

func changeNames(){
    for name in names {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rename \(name)",
                                      message: "What would you like to call \(name)?",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
            textField.text = name
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
            print("User changed \(name) to \(alert!.textFields![0].text)")
            //Don't continue the loop until now
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Thanks

---

### Revisiting this question several years later

The basic premise of the question is totally flawed, I was coming at it from a VBA devs perspective with insufficient understanding of asynchronous code.

A few things wrong with this approach:

1. Collecting lots of information through UIAlertControllers is really bad UX - A dedicated UI would be better
2. A for loop is a bad way to express the intent - A stack of 'itemsToChange' would be better; the completion of one item could initiate the handler for the next until the stack is empty

Comment: You could instead of using a for loop, loop recursively through the list of names

Comment: Why you using for-loop ??

Comment: definitely not like this... what do you want to achieve? why do you need a for-loop here?

Comment: @holex It's part of a UICollectionView that has a reusable function that takes an action closure and applies it in a for-loop to all selected items in the collectionview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looping is hard with asynchronous code, I'd rather go with recursion:

```
func showChangeAlerts(for texts: [String]) {
  guard let value = texts.first else { return }

  let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rename \(value)",
    message: "What would you like to call \(value)?",
    preferredStyle: .alert)
  alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField
    textField.text = value
  })
  alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert, weak self] (_) in
    let newValue = alert?.textFields![0].text ?? ""
    print("User changed \(value) to \(newValue)")
    self?.showChangeAlerts(for: Array(texts.dropFirst()))
  }))
  self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

You pass in an array of strings, and this method will work through them until all have been processed.

**EDIT**

Ok, just saw that Ron Nabuurs beat me with a very similar solution :) The main difference is that my method doesn't use the additional iterator parameter, but "consumes" strings from the provided array until it's empty. But the principle is the same.

Comment: I do like this anwer more, because its cleaner :)

Comment: @RonNabuurs hehe, thanks... I think the OP got a good solution either way.

Comment: The functionality is the same, so if it look stupid but it works it ain't stupid haha

Comment: @dr_barto this is implemented and works a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this because I don't have a mac at the moment. And my Swift is rusty, but the general Idea is there :P. Recursion is the thing to do here:

```
var names = ["Bob","Kate"]

func changeNames(names: [String], iterator: Int = 0){
    if (names.count >= iterator) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rename \(names[iterator])",
                                      message: "What would you like to call \(names[iterator])?",
                                      preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
            textField.text = names[iterator]
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
            print("User changed \(names[iterator]) to \(alert!.textFields![0].text)")
            changeNames(names, iterator + 1)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer of @dr_barto is a bit cleaner with `dropFirst()`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I really appreciate you taking the time. I've gone with dr_barto's solution just for the .dropFirst() feature.