# Multiple alerts on top of each other in swift

Tags: swift, alert, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

Right now I'm getting error: 
Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController: 0x7f9af9016200  on CollectionViewController: 0x7f9af750d620 which is already presenting (null)

Is there way i can stack alerts in swift?
There is my code, it shows alert if item is posted more than day ago.
Two ways i have tried to do this but not succeeded.

1. Pause the for loop until i press yes or no.
2. Present many alerts on top of each others

Any solutions how to manage to do this?

```
for p in json! {
     if self.checkDaysPassed(postDate: p["uploadedTime"] as! String) > 1 {
     print("more than one day passed, sell item?")

     let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sell this item", message: "This item has been unused for a day", preferredStyle: .alert)
     alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default){ (action) in
           print("pressed yes")
     })
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel){ (action) in
          print("pressed no")
     })
     self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than multiple consecutive alerts present a table view with a `Sell` button in each row and a global `Cancel` button.

Comment: it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732371/how-to-use-uialertcontroller-in-for-loop

Comment: @MJICT do you want to show only one alert? Or for all cases where condition is true but one after another alert?

Comment: @Kamran I want to show alert one after another, every time the condition is true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show alerts after one another, i would suggest to add this recursive code,

Add a `class` variable for `messages` and fill the `array` for all the `true` conditions. After that you have to just call the `showAlert` method that will handle showing all the messages one by one.

```
class YourClass {

   var messages: [String] = []


   func yourMethod() {
       for p in json! {
         if self.checkDaysPassed(postDate: p["uploadedTime"] as! String) > 1 {
             messages.append("This item has been unused for a day")
         }
       }
       self.showAlert()
   }

   private func showAlert() {
        guard self.messages.count > 0 else { return }

        let message = self.messages.first

        func removeAndShowNextMessage() {
            self.messages.removeFirst()
            self.showAlert()
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sell this item", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default){ (action) in
            print("pressed yes")
            removeAndShowNextMessage()

        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel){ (action) in
            print("pressed no")
            removeAndShowNextMessage()
        })

        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```